# Not able to delete permission(klaravel/ntrust) - Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, acl

I'am using klaravel/ntrust package for ACL in my laravel 5.3 application.
Everything working fine except deleting permission.

**config/ntrust.php**

```
'admin' => [

    User table name     
    'table' => 'cushbu_admin',

    User model      
    'model' => 'Modules\Admin\Models\Admin',

    Ntrust Role Model
   'role' => 'Modules\Admin\Models\AdminRole',

    Ntrust Roles Table     
    'roles_table' => 'cushbu_admin_roles',

    Ntrust Permission Model
    'permission' => 'Modules\Admin\Models\AdminPermission',

    Ntrust Permissions Table
   'permissions_table' => 'cushbu_admin_permissions',

    Ntrust permission_role Table
    'permission_role_table' => 'cushbu_admin_permission_role',

    Ntrust role_user Table
   'role_user_table' => 'cushbu_admin_role_user',

    User Foreign key on Ntrust's role_user Table (Pivot)
    'user_foreign_key' => 'user_id',

   Role Foreign key on Ntrust's role_user and permission_role Tables 
   (Pivot)
    'role_foreign_key' => 'role_id',

    Permission Foreign key on Ntrust's permission_role Table (Pivot)
    'permission_foreign_key' => 'permission_id',

],
```

when i try to delete i'am getting this error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'admin_role_id'
>   in 'field list' (SQL: select `admin_role_id` from
>   `admin_permission_role` where `admin_permission_id` = 3)

I haven't specified admin_role_id, admin_permission_id anywhere, rather exist role_id, permission_id.

**Permission model**

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Admin\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Klaravel\Ntrust\Traits\NtrustPermissionTrait;
use Vinkla\Hashids\Facades\Hashids;

class AdminPermission extends Model
{
    use NtrustPermissionTrait;

    /*
     * Role profile to get value from ntrust config file.
     */
    protected static $roleProfile = 'admin';

    protected $table = 'cushbu_admin_permissions' ;

    protected $fillable = ['name','display_name'];

    //Get hashid
    public function getRouteKey() {
        return Hashids::encode($this->getKey());
    }
}
```

### permission_table

id ,name, display_name, description

### permission_role_table

permission_id ,role_id

Comment: Could you please share your DB table strucutre of permission_role_table & .permissions_table

Comment: Try by keeping the value of protected static $roleProfile as '' instead of admin.

Comment: i have 2 role profiles in config 'admin' and 'user'. default is set to 'admin'

Comment: Have you try with the "detachPermission" function. First find out the role and detach that permission. You can detach single or multiple permissions see the documentation here : https://github.com/klaravel/ntrust/blob/master/src/Ntrust/Traits/NtrustRoleTrait.php

Comment: renamed table fields to admin_permission_id, admin_role_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed permission_id, role_id to admin_permission_id, admin_role_id respectively in database.that solved the issue.

Comment: I think you have missed below steps when you have to install this package:
User relation to roles

Now generate the Ntrust migration:

php artisan ntrust:migration {name}
Profile {name} name of profile which you have in file config/ntrust.php section profiles.

It will generate the <timestamp>_<user>_ntrust_setup_tables.php migration. You may now run it with the artisan migrate command:

php artisan migrate